# How to open a word document in a new tab/window without downloading the file using HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I dont want to download the word document instead I just wish to view the file in the browser itself.
How is this possible with HTML and JavaScript ?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as the other question is about browser plugins whereas this one seems more about configuring this from the hosting webpage.

Comment: @Ganesh but that's not possible.

Comment: It would still be a different question if my interpretation were correct (though I'm not very sure anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the main browsers have plugins that you can install that allow you to view word documents. This is one for Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpointviewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en

It is under Office Apps.

Here is one for firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-docs-viewer-pdf-doc-doc/

Answer (score -2):

This is the reason why you use PDF documents.

Go to your word document and save it as a pdf. You can do it via the ribbons.